# Google map custom marker based on database

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In 2 weeks I explored much about Google maps. I am try read a forum and tutorial. But I got this problem when I am going to develop a GIS web. I am using Google maps apiv3, postgre database, and php. I have so much row in my database. Now I only can show multiple marker based on my database, but what I after is **the marker have a unique icon based on column content in database** like a type 1 = 1.png type 2 = 2.png. **the problem is the type is too many**, so it is impossible to definition them by manual (because so many type, I already have about 30 type of content in database column ) . I get database value using json. I've already try read forum and some tutorial, but I can't find the answer. sorry for my bad english. please help me, thanks. 
this is the code index.php and json.php :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(){
    var peta;
    var gambar_tanda;
    gambar_tanda = 'assets/images/enseval.jpg';
    var x = new Array();
    var y = new Array();
    var customer_name = new Array();
    var rayon_name = new Array();
    // posisi default peta saat diload
    var lokasibaru = new google.maps.LatLng( -1.2653859,116.83119999999997);
    var petaoption = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: lokasibaru,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),petaoption);
        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: ''
        });
    // memanggil function ambilpeta() untuk menampilkan koordinat
        url = "json.php";
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg){
            for(i=0;i<msg.enseval.customer.length;i++){
                x[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].x;
                y[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].y;
                customer_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                //rayon_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_rayon
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].x),parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].y));
                tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: point,
                            map: peta,
                            icon: gambar_tanda,
                            clickable: true
                });
            bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer  );
            }
        }
        });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(data);
    infowindow.open(peta, tanda);
    });
}
</script>
```

---

```
<?php  
require ('config.php');
$rayon = $_POST['rayon'];
$cabang = $_POST['org_id'];
//echo "$rayon, $cabang, $rayonhasil";
$sql = "SELECT distinct org_id, customer_name, attribute16, attribute17 FROM hasilgis";
$data = pg_query($sql);
$json = '{"enseval": {';
$json .= '"customer":[ ';
while($x = pg_fetch_array($data)){
    $json .= '{';
    $json .= '"id_customer":"'.$x['org_id'].'",
        "nama_customer":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['customer_name']).'",
        "x":"'.$x['attribute17'].'",
        "y":"'.$x['attribute16'].'"
    },';
}
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
$json .= ']';
$json .= '}}';

echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the problem :)

The only thing you must do is to generate icons for all types. You don't have to do it manually - just create a scipt that will generate icons of different colors for every type and name it like `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ...

Pass type via your json message and than on client side create icon url dynamically:

```
gambar_tanda = 'assets/images/'+msg.enseval.customer[i].type+'.jpg';
```

Comment: thanks so much.but there is to many various of type, because on my data, one object have 10-30 type and i have  43 object plus there is have a unique type, so may be i have 30*43 type. but what make this case simple is i just need to show one object for every running program. so can i still rename like 1.jpg? sorry fo my bad english.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean - you can name your icons whatever you like. You only must define which type would you like to show for every object - it doesn't have to correspond to the type obtained from DB.

Comment: i solve this, i miss the main idea, thanks so much gawi .. :)